# make the last column of the dynamically generated table floating

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a function that takes json as input and then generates a table but as the data is too much, the no. of columns are more. Even though i have a horizontal scroll bar, to see the last column(most important column), too much of scrolling needs to be done.
I am new to css and do not know if it possible to float the last column, so that even if i do not scroll, the last column is always wrapped in the right portion of the table and opens when i scroll it.
So that i can see the last column of the table eveytime.

Here is the sample json data:

```
var myContacts = [{
    "owner": "swapneil",
    "fleet_name": "RancorService",
    "creation_date": "09-03-2020",
    "environment": "RancorService/JP",
    "vip_port": 80,
    "partition": "YES",
    "protocol": "HTTP",
    "monitor": "Consistent (http-ping)",
    "lbset": "Consistent",
    "predictor": "Consistent",
    "spillover": "Consistent",
    "vip_cka": "Consistent :(NO)",
    "max_conns": "Consistent : (36)",
    "vip_cipher": null,
    "vip_cip": "Consistent",
    "vip_tier": "Consistent(Tier1)",
    "vip_siloed": "Consistent(Non-SILOED)",
    "vip_globalized": "Consistent(Non-GLOBALIZED)",
    "vip_dedicated": "Consistent(Non-DEDICATED_VIP)",
    "vip_retail_tag": "Consistent(RETAIL_TAG)",
    "down_stat_flush": "Consistent :(ENABLED)",
    "vip_type": "Consistent (BACKEND)",
    "server_port": "Consistent",
    "vip_server_timeout": "Consistent",
    "vip_client_timeout": "Consistent",
    "persistent_method": "Consistent",
    "persistent_timeout": "Consistent"

  },
  {
    "owner": "swapneil",
    "fleet_name": "RancorService",
    "creation_date": "09-03-2020",
    "environment": "RancorService/JP",
    "vip_port": 443,
    "partition": "YES",
    "protocol": "TCP",
    "monitor": "NC",
    "lbset": "NC (>1 Vip's in same LB)",
    "predictor": "NC (leastconns,ROUNDROBINSHOULD BE ROUNDROBIN)",
    "spillover": "Consistent",
    "vip_cka": "Consistent :(NO)",
    "max_conns": "Consistent : (9000)",
    "vip_cipher": null,
    "vip_cip": "Consistent",
    "vip_tier": "Consistent(Non-Tier1)",
    "vip_siloed": "Consistent(Non-SILOED)",
    "vip_globalized": "Consistent(Non-GLOBALIZED)",
    "vip_dedicated": "Consistent(Non-DEDICATED_VIP)",
    "vip_retail_tag": "Consistent(RETAIL_TAG)",
    "down_stat_flush": "Consistent :(ENABLED)",
    "vip_type": "Consistent (BACKEND)",
    "server_port": "Consistent",
    "vip_server_timeout": "Consistent",
    "vip_client_timeout": "Consistent",
    "persistent_method": "Consistent",
    "persistent_timeout": "Consistent"

  },
  {
    "owner": "swapneil",
    "fleet_name": "RegionAwareBaseLayer",
    "creation_date": "09-03-2020",
    "environment": "RegionAwareBaseLayer/NA",
    "vip_port": 80,
    "partition": "YES",
    "protocol": "HTTP",
    "monitor": "Consistent (http-ping)",
    "lbset": "Consistent",
    "predictor": "Consistent",
    "spillover": "Consistent",
    "vip_cka": "Consistent :(NO)",
    "max_conns": "Consistent : (56)",
    "vip_cipher": null,
    "vip_cip": "Consistent",
    "vip_tier": "NC : >1 VIP's MISSING TIER-1 TAG",
    "vip_siloed": "Consistent(Non-SILOED)",
    "vip_globalized": "Consistent(GLOBALIZED)",
    "vip_dedicated": "Consistent(Non-DEDICATED_VIP)",
    "vip_retail_tag": "Consistent(RETAIL_TAG)",
    "down_stat_flush": "Consistent :(ENABLED)",
    "vip_type": "Consistent (BACKEND)",
    "server_port": "Consistent",
    "vip_server_timeout": "Consistent",
    "vip_client_timeout": "Consistent",
    "persistent_method": "Consistent",
    "persistent_timeout": "Consistent"

  },
  {
    "owner": "swapneil",
    "fleet_name": "RegionAwareBaseLayer",
    "creation_date": "09-03-2020",
    "environment": "RegionAwareBaseLayer/NA",
    "vip_port": 443,
    "partition": "NO",
    "protocol": "TCP",
    "monitor": "Consistent (ssl-ping)",
    "lbset": "Consistent",
    "predictor": "NC :SHOULD BE ROUNDROBIN",
    "spillover": "Consistent",
    "vip_cka": "NC : SHOULD BE DISABLED (YES)",
    "max_conns": "Consistent : (9000)",
    "vip_cipher": null,
    "vip_cip": "Consistent",
    "vip_tier": "Consistent(Tier1)",
    "vip_siloed": "Consistent(Non-SILOED)",
    "vip_globalized": "Consistent(Non-GLOBALIZED)",
    "vip_dedicated": "Consistent(Non-DEDICATED_VIP)",
    "vip_retail_tag": "Consistent(RETAIL_TAG)",
    "down_stat_flush": "Consistent :(ENABLED)",
    "vip_type": "Consistent (BACKEND)",
    "server_port": "Consistent",
    "vip_server_timeout": "Consistent",
    "vip_client_timeout": "Consistent",
    "persistent_method": "Consistent",
    "persistent_timeout": "Consistent"

  },
  {
    "owner": "swapneil",
    "fleet_name": "RegionMappingService",
    "creation_date": "09-03-2020",
    "environment": "RegionMappingService/EU",
    "vip_port": 80,
    "partition": "YES",
    "protocol": "HTTP",
    "monitor": "Consistent (http-ping)",
    "lbset": "Consistent",
    "predictor": "Consistent",
    "spillover": "Consistent",
    "vip_cka": "Consistent :(NO)",
    "max_conns": "Consistent : (16)",
    "vip_cipher": null,
    "vip_cip": "Consistent",
    "vip_tier": "Consistent(Tier1)",
    "vip_siloed": "Consistent(Non-SILOED)",
    "vip_globalized": "Consistent(Non-GLOBALIZED)",
    "vip_dedicated": "Consistent(Non-DEDICATED_VIP)",
    "vip_retail_tag": "Consistent(RETAIL_TAG)",
    "down_stat_flush": "Consistent :(ENABLED)",
    "vip_type": "Consistent (BACKEND)",
    "server_port": "Consistent",
    "vip_server_timeout": "Consistent",
    "vip_client_timeout": "Consistent",
    "persistent_method": "Consistent",
    "persistent_timeout": "Consistent"

  },
  {
    "owner": "swapneil",
    "fleet_name": "RegionMappingService",
    "creation_date": "09-03-2020",
    "environment": "RegionMappingService/EU",
    "vip_port": 443,
    "partition": "YES",
    "protocol": "TCP",
    "monitor": "NC",
    "lbset": "NC (>1 Vip's in same LB)",
    "predictor": "NC :SHOULD BE ROUNDROBIN",
    "spillover": "Consistent",
    "vip_cka": "Consistent :(NO)",
    "max_conns": "Consistent : (9000)",
    "vip_cipher": null,
    "vip_cip": "Consistent",
    "vip_tier": "Consistent(Non-Tier1)",
    "vip_siloed": "Consistent(Non-SILOED)",
    "vip_globalized": "Consistent(Non-GLOBALIZED)",
    "vip_dedicated": "Consistent(Non-DEDICATED_VIP)",
    "vip_retail_tag": "Consistent(RETAIL_TAG)",
    "down_stat_flush": "Consistent :(ENABLED)",
    "vip_type": "Consistent (BACKEND)",
    "server_port": "Consistent",
    "vip_server_timeout": "Consistent",
    "vip_client_timeout": "Consistent",
    "persistent_method": "Consistent",
    "persistent_timeout": "Consistent"

  },
  {
    "owner": "swapneil",
    "fleet_name": "RegionAwareBaseLayer",
    "creation_date": "09-03-2020",
    "environment": "RABLIndexer/EU",
    "vip_port": 80,
    "partition": "NO",
    "protocol": "HTTP",
    "monitor": "Consistent (http-ping)",
    "lbset": "Consistent",
    "predictor": "Consistent",
    "spillover": "Consistent",
    "vip_cka": "NC : SHOULD BE DISABLED (YES)",
    "max_conns": "MAX-CONNS WITH DEFAULT VALUE : 15",
    "vip_cipher": null,
    "vip_cip": "Consistent",
    "vip_tier": "Consistent(Non-Tier1)",
    "vip_siloed": "Consistent(Non-SILOED)",
    "vip_globalized": "Consistent(Non-GLOBALIZED)",
    "vip_dedicated": "Consistent(Non-DEDICATED_VIP)",
    "vip_retail_tag": "Consistent(RETAIL_TAG)",
    "down_stat_flush": "Consistent :(ENABLED)",
    "vip_type": "Consistent (BACKEND)",
    "server_port": "Consistent",
    "vip_server_timeout": "Consistent",
    "vip_client_timeout": "Consistent",
    "persistent_method": "Consistent",
    "persistent_timeout": "Consistent"

  },
  {
    "owner": "swapneil",
    "fleet_name": "RegionMappingService",
    "creation_date": "09-03-2020",
    "environment": "RegionMappingService/JP",
    "vip_port": 80,
    "partition": "YES",
    "protocol": "HTTP",
    "monitor": "NC",
    "lbset": "Consistent",
    "predictor": "Consistent",
    "spillover": "Consistent",
    "vip_cka": "Consistent :(NO)",
    "max_conns": "Consistent : (40)",
    "vip_cipher": null,
    "vip_cip": "Consistent",
    "vip_tier": "Consistent(Tier1)",
    "vip_siloed": "Consistent(Non-SILOED)",
    "vip_globalized": "Consistent(Non-GLOBALIZED)",
    "vip_dedicated": "Consistent(Non-DEDICATED_VIP)",
    "vip_retail_tag": "Consistent(RETAIL_TAG)",
    "down_stat_flush": "Consistent :(ENABLED)",
    "vip_type": "Consistent (BACKEND)",
    "server_port": "Consistent",
    "vip_server_timeout": "Consistent",
    "vip_client_timeout": "Consistent",
    "persistent_method": "Consistent",
    "persistent_timeout": "Consistent"

  },
  {
    "owner": "swapneil",
    "fleet_name": "RegionMappingService",
    "creation_date": "09-03-2020",
    "environment": "RegionMappingService/JP",
    "vip_port": 443,
    "partition": "YES",
    "protocol": "TCP",
    "monitor": "NC",
    "lbset": "NC (>1 Vip's in same LB)",
    "predictor": "NC :SHOULD BE ROUNDROBIN",
    "spillover": "Consistent",
    "vip_cka": "Consistent :(NO)",
    "max_conns": "Consistent : (9000)",
    "vip_cipher": null,
    "vip_cip": "Consistent",
    "vip_tier": "Consistent(Non-Tier1)",
    "vip_siloed": "Consistent(Non-SILOED)",
    "vip_globalized": "Consistent(Non-GLOBALIZED)",
    "vip_dedicated": "Consistent(Non-DEDICATED_VIP)",
    "vip_retail_tag": "Consistent(RETAIL_TAG)",
    "down_stat_flush": "Consistent :(ENABLED)",
    "vip_type": "Consistent (BACKEND)",
    "server_port": "Consistent",
    "vip_server_timeout": "Consistent",
    "vip_client_timeout": "Consistent",
    "persistent_method": "Consistent",
    "persistent_timeout": "Consistent"

  }
];
```

and here is the function that converts the json into table:

```
function generateDynamicTable(myContacts) {
  var noOfContacts = myContacts.length;

  if (noOfContacts > 0) {


    // CREATE DYNAMIC TABLE.
    var table = document.createElement("table");
    table.style.width = '50%';
    table.setAttribute('border', '1');
    table.setAttribute('cellspacing', '0');
    table.setAttribute('cellpadding', '5');

    // retrieve column header ('Name', 'Email', and 'Mobile')

    var col = []; // define an empty array
    for (var i = 0; i < noOfContacts; i++) {
      for (var key in myContacts[i]) {
        if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
          col.push(key);
        }
      }
    }

    // CREATE TABLE HEAD .
    var tHead = document.createElement("thead");


    // CREATE ROW FOR TABLE HEAD .
    var hRow = document.createElement("tr");

    // ADD COLUMN HEADER TO ROW OF TABLE HEAD.
    for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
      var th = document.createElement("th");
      th.innerHTML = col[i];
      hRow.appendChild(th);
    }
    tHead.appendChild(hRow);
    table.appendChild(tHead);

    // CREATE TABLE BODY .
    var tBody = document.createElement("tbody");

    // ADD COLUMN HEADER TO ROW OF TABLE HEAD.
    for (var i = 0; i < noOfContacts; i++) {

      var bRow = document.createElement("tr"); // CREATE ROW FOR EACH RECORD


      for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
        var td = document.createElement("td");
        if (col[j] == 'monitor' && myContacts[i][col[j]] == 'NC') {
          var a = document.createElement('a');
          var linkText = document.createTextNode("Ext. link");
          a.appendChild(linkText);
          a.title = "Check details";
          a.href = "http://example.com";
          td.appendChild( a );
        } else {
          td.innerHTML = myContacts[i][col[j]];
        };
        bRow.appendChild(td);
      }
      tBody.appendChild(bRow)

    }
    table.appendChild(tBody);


    // FINALLY ADD THE NEWLY CREATED TABLE WITH JSON DATA TO A CONTAINER.
    var divContainer = document.getElementById("demo");
    divContainer.appendChild(table);

  }
};
```

Can anyone please help??

After the suggestion in the comment box i did the following change:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.3.0/css/fixedColumns.dataTables.min.css">
<style type="text/css">
        /* Ensure that the demo table scrolls */
        th, td { white-space: nowrap; }
        div.dataTables_wrapper {
            width: 800px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.3.0/js/dataTables.fixedColumns.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
            scrollY:        "300px",
            scrollX:        true,
            scrollCollapse: true,
            paging:         false,
            fixedColumns:   {
                leftColumns: 1,
                rightColumns: 1
            }
        } );
    } );
</script>
```

and added these lines in the generateDynamicTable() function:

```
        table.setAttribute('id','example');
        table.setAttribute('class', 'stripe row-border order-column');
```

But still i am not getting the result.

Comment: [Here's a Bootstrap example](https://codepen.io/siremilomir/pen/reQRoa)

Comment: @kmoser 's example seems fine, you can also take a look at [DataTables](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/examples/initialisation/left_right_columns.html)

Comment: @kmoser I am using only javascript and no jquery. "ReferenceError: $ is not defined". I get this error

Comment: You can download one with jQuery included.

Comment: @Uroš. I have updated in question. Please see that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've opted to give DataTables a try you don't need to write your own code for generating the table from json data. DataTables already has this: `data: jsonTableData`, but you do need thead (declare columns), in the example bellow I wrote a simple way of automatically generating those. Also table has to exist on the html DOM for DataTables to work, hence why you will find an empty table with id=example in the body section of the html. I've placed comments in the code for clarification, but if you need something explained further feel free to ask.

Here is the code snippet:

```js
// variables

var columns_title = [];

var jsonTableData;

var myContacts1 = [{
    "owner": "swapneil",
    "fleet_name": "RancorService",
    "creation_date": "09-03-2020",
    "environment": "RancorService/JP",
    "vip_port": 80,
    "partition": "YES",
    "protocol": "HTTP",
    "monitor": "Consistent (http-ping)",
    "lbset": "Consistent",
    "predictor": "Consistent",
    "spillover": "Consistent",
    "vip_cka": "Consistent :(NO)",
    "max_conns": "Consistent : (36)",
    "vip_cipher": null,
    "vip_cip": "Consistent",
    "vip_tier": "Consistent(Tier1)",
    "vip_siloed": "Consistent(Non-SILOED)",
    "vip_globalized": "Consistent(Non-GLOBALIZED)",
    "vip_dedicated": "Consistent(Non-DEDICATED_VIP)",
    "vip_retail_tag": "Consistent(RETAIL_TAG)",
    "down_stat_flush": "Consistent :(ENABLED)",
    "vip_type": "Consistent (BACKEND)",
    "server_port": "Consistent",
    "vip_server_timeout": "Consistent",
    "vip_client_timeout": "Consistent",
    "persistent_method": "Consistent",
    "persistent_timeout": "Consistent"

  },
  {
    "owner": "swapneil",
    "fleet_name": "RancorService",
    "creation_date": "09-03-2020",
    "environment": "RancorService/JP",
    "vip_port": 443,
    "partition": "YES",
    "protocol": "TCP",
    "monitor": "NC",
    "lbset": "NC (>1 Vip's in same LB)",
    "predictor": "NC (leastconns,ROUNDROBINSHOULD BE ROUNDROBIN)",
    "spillover": "Consistent",
    "vip_cka": "Consistent :(NO)",
    "max_conns": "Consistent : (9000)",
    "vip_cipher": null,
    "vip_cip": "Consistent",
    "vip_tier": "Consistent(Non-Tier1)",
    "vip_siloed": "Consistent(Non-SILOED)",
    "vip_globalized": "Consistent(Non-GLOBALIZED)",
    "vip_dedicated": "Consistent(Non-DEDICATED_VIP)",
    "vip_retail_tag": "Consistent(RETAIL_TAG)",
    "down_stat_flush": "Consistent :(ENABLED)",
    "vip_type": "Consistent (BACKEND)",
    "server_port": "Consistent",
    "vip_server_timeout": "Consistent",
    "vip_client_timeout": "Consistent",
    "persistent_method": "Consistent",
    "persistent_timeout": "Consistent"

  },
  {
    "owner": "swapneil",
    "fleet_name": "RegionAwareBaseLayer",
    "creation_date": "09-03-2020",
    "environment": "RegionAwareBaseLayer/NA",
    "vip_port": 80,
    "partition": "YES",
    "protocol": "HTTP",
    "monitor": "Consistent (http-ping)",
    "lbset": "Consistent",
    "predictor": "Consistent",
    "spillover": "Consistent",
    "vip_cka": "Consistent :(NO)",
    "max_conns": "Consistent : (56)",
    "vip_cipher": null,
    "vip_cip": "Consistent",
    "vip_tier": "NC : >1 VIP's MISSING TIER-1 TAG",
    "vip_siloed": "Consistent(Non-SILOED)",
    "vip_globalized": "Consistent(GLOBALIZED)",
    "vip_dedicated": "Consistent(Non-DEDICATED_VIP)",
    "vip_retail_tag": "Consistent(RETAIL_TAG)",
    "down_stat_flush": "Consistent :(ENABLED)",
    "vip_type": "Consistent (BACKEND)",
    "server_port": "Consistent",
    "vip_server_timeout": "Consistent",
    "vip_client_timeout": "Consistent",
    "persistent_method": "Consistent",
    "persistent_timeout": "Consistent"

  },
  {
    "owner": "swapneil",
    "fleet_name": "RegionAwareBaseLayer",
    "creation_date": "09-03-2020",
    "environment": "RegionAwareBaseLayer/NA",
    "vip_port": 443,
    "partition": "NO",
    "protocol": "TCP",
    "monitor": "Consistent (ssl-ping)",
    "lbset": "Consistent",
    "predictor": "NC :SHOULD BE ROUNDROBIN",
    "spillover": "Consistent",
    "vip_cka": "NC : SHOULD BE DISABLED (YES)",
    "max_conns": "Consistent : (9000)",
    "vip_cipher": null,
    "vip_cip": "Consistent",
    "vip_tier": "Consistent(Tier1)",
    "vip_siloed": "Consistent(Non-SILOED)",
    "vip_globalized": "Consistent(Non-GLOBALIZED)",
    "vip_dedicated": "Consistent(Non-DEDICATED_VIP)",
    "vip_retail_tag": "Consistent(RETAIL_TAG)",
    "down_stat_flush": "Consistent :(ENABLED)",
    "vip_type": "Consistent (BACKEND)",
    "server_port": "Consistent",
    "vip_server_timeout": "Consistent",
    "vip_client_timeout": "Consistent",
    "persistent_method": "Consistent",
    "persistent_timeout": "Consistent"

  },
  {
    "owner": "swapneil",
    "fleet_name": "RegionMappingService",
    "creation_date": "09-03-2020",
    "environment": "RegionMappingService/EU",
    "vip_port": 80,
    "partition": "YES",
    "protocol": "HTTP",
    "monitor": "Consistent (http-ping)",
    "lbset": "Consistent",
    "predictor": "Consistent",
    "spillover": "Consistent",
    "vip_cka": "Consistent :(NO)",
    "max_conns": "Consistent : (16)",
    "vip_cipher": null,
    "vip_cip": "Consistent",
    "vip_tier": "Consistent(Tier1)",
    "vip_siloed": "Consistent(Non-SILOED)",
    "vip_globalized": "Consistent(Non-GLOBALIZED)",
    "vip_dedicated": "Consistent(Non-DEDICATED_VIP)",
    "vip_retail_tag": "Consistent(RETAIL_TAG)",
    "down_stat_flush": "Consistent :(ENABLED)",
    "vip_type": "Consistent (BACKEND)",
    "server_port": "Consistent",
    "vip_server_timeout": "Consistent",
    "vip_client_timeout": "Consistent",
    "persistent_method": "Consistent",
    "persistent_timeout": "Consistent"

  },
  {
    "owner": "swapneil",
    "fleet_name": "RegionMappingService",
    "creation_date": "09-03-2020",
    "environment": "RegionMappingService/EU",
    "vip_port": 443,
    "partition": "YES",
    "protocol": "TCP",
    "monitor": "NC",
    "lbset": "NC (>1 Vip's in same LB)",
    "predictor": "NC :SHOULD BE ROUNDROBIN",
    "spillover": "Consistent",
    "vip_cka": "Consistent :(NO)",
    "max_conns": "Consistent : (9000)",
    "vip_cipher": null,
    "vip_cip": "Consistent",
    "vip_tier": "Consistent(Non-Tier1)",
    "vip_siloed": "Consistent(Non-SILOED)",
    "vip_globalized": "Consistent(Non-GLOBALIZED)",
    "vip_dedicated": "Consistent(Non-DEDICATED_VIP)",
    "vip_retail_tag": "Consistent(RETAIL_TAG)",
    "down_stat_flush": "Consistent :(ENABLED)",
    "vip_type": "Consistent (BACKEND)",
    "server_port": "Consistent",
    "vip_server_timeout": "Consistent",
    "vip_client_timeout": "Consistent",
    "persistent_method": "Consistent",
    "persistent_timeout": "Consistent"

  },
  {
    "owner": "swapneil",
    "fleet_name": "RegionAwareBaseLayer",
    "creation_date": "09-03-2020",
    "environment": "RABLIndexer/EU",
    "vip_port": 80,
    "partition": "NO",
    "protocol": "HTTP",
    "monitor": "Consistent (http-ping)",
    "lbset": "Consistent",
    "predictor": "Consistent",
    "spillover": "Consistent",
    "vip_cka": "NC : SHOULD BE DISABLED (YES)",
    "max_conns": "MAX-CONNS WITH DEFAULT VALUE : 15",
    "vip_cipher": null,
    "vip_cip": "Consistent",
    "vip_tier": "Consistent(Non-Tier1)",
    "vip_siloed": "Consistent(Non-SILOED)",
    "vip_globalized": "Consistent(Non-GLOBALIZED)",
    "vip_dedicated": "Consistent(Non-DEDICATED_VIP)",
    "vip_retail_tag": "Consistent(RETAIL_TAG)",
    "down_stat_flush": "Consistent :(ENABLED)",
    "vip_type": "Consistent (BACKEND)",
    "server_port": "Consistent",
    "vip_server_timeout": "Consistent",
    "vip_client_timeout": "Consistent",
    "persistent_method": "Consistent",
    "persistent_timeout": "Consistent"

  },
  {
    "owner": "swapneil",
    "fleet_name": "RegionMappingService",
    "creation_date": "09-03-2020",
    "environment": "RegionMappingService/JP",
    "vip_port": 80,
    "partition": "YES",
    "protocol": "HTTP",
    "monitor": "NC",
    "lbset": "Consistent",
    "predictor": "Consistent",
    "spillover": "Consistent",
    "vip_cka": "Consistent :(NO)",
    "max_conns": "Consistent : (40)",
    "vip_cipher": null,
    "vip_cip": "Consistent",
    "vip_tier": "Consistent(Tier1)",
    "vip_siloed": "Consistent(Non-SILOED)",
    "vip_globalized": "Consistent(Non-GLOBALIZED)",
    "vip_dedicated": "Consistent(Non-DEDICATED_VIP)",
    "vip_retail_tag": "Consistent(RETAIL_TAG)",
    "down_stat_flush": "Consistent :(ENABLED)",
    "vip_type": "Consistent (BACKEND)",
    "server_port": "Consistent",
    "vip_server_timeout": "Consistent",
     "vip_client_timeout": "Consistent",
    "persistent_method": "Consistent",
    "persistent_timeout": "Consistent"

  },
  {
    "owner": "swapneil",
    "fleet_name": "RegionMappingService",
    "creation_date": "09-03-2020",
    "environment": "RegionMappingService/JP",
    "vip_port": 443,
    "partition": "YES",
    "protocol": "TCP",
    "monitor": "NC",
    "lbset": "NC (>1 Vip's in same LB)",
    "predictor": "NC :SHOULD BE ROUNDROBIN",
    "spillover": "Consistent",
    "vip_cka": "Consistent :(NO)",
    "max_conns": "Consistent : (9000)",
    "vip_cipher": null,
    "vip_cip": "Consistent",
    "vip_tier": "Consistent(Non-Tier1)",
    "vip_siloed": "Consistent(Non-SILOED)",
    "vip_globalized": "Consistent(Non-GLOBALIZED)",
    "vip_dedicated": "Consistent(Non-DEDICATED_VIP)",
    "vip_retail_tag": "Consistent(RETAIL_TAG)",
    "down_stat_flush": "Consistent :(ENABLED)",
    "vip_type": "Consistent (BACKEND)",
    "server_port": "Consistent",
    "vip_server_timeout": "Consistent",
    "vip_client_timeout": "Consistent",
    "persistent_method": "Consistent",
    "persistent_timeout": "Consistent"

  }
]; 

var myContacts2 = [{
    "owner": "2_swapneil",
    "fleet_name": "2_RancorService",
    "creation_date": "09-03-2020",
    "environment": "RancorService/JP",
    "vip_port": 80,
    "partition": "YES",
    "protocol": "HTTP",
    "monitor": "Consistent (http-ping)",
    "lbset": "Consistent",
    "predictor": "Consistent",
    "spillover": "Consistent",
    "vip_cka": "Consistent :(NO)",
    "max_conns": "Consistent : (36)",
    "vip_cipher": null,
    "vip_cip": "Consistent",
    "vip_tier": "Consistent(Tier1)",
    "vip_siloed": "Consistent(Non-SILOED)",
    "vip_globalized": "Consistent(Non-GLOBALIZED)",
    "vip_dedicated": "Consistent(Non-DEDICATED_VIP)",
    "vip_retail_tag": "Consistent(RETAIL_TAG)",
    "down_stat_flush": "Consistent :(ENABLED)",
    "vip_type": "Consistent (BACKEND)",
    "server_port": "Consistent",
    "vip_server_timeout": "Consistent",
    "vip_client_timeout": "Consistent",
    "persistent_method": "Consistent",
    "persistent_timeout": "2Consistent"
  },
  {
    "owner": "2_swapneil",
    "fleet_name": "2_RegionMappingService",
    "creation_date": "09-03-2020",
    "environment": "RegionMappingService/JP",
    "vip_port": 443,
    "partition": "YES",
    "protocol": "TCP",
    "monitor": "NC",
    "lbset": "NC (>1 Vip's in same LB)",
    "predictor": "NC :SHOULD BE ROUNDROBIN",
    "spillover": "Consistent",
    "vip_cka": "Consistent :(NO)",
    "max_conns": "Consistent : (9000)",
    "vip_cipher": null,
    "vip_cip": "Consistent",
    "vip_tier": "Consistent(Non-Tier1)",
    "vip_siloed": "Consistent(Non-SILOED)",
    "vip_globalized": "Consistent(Non-GLOBALIZED)",
    "vip_dedicated": "Consistent(Non-DEDICATED_VIP)",
    "vip_retail_tag": "Consistent(RETAIL_TAG)",
    "down_stat_flush": "Consistent :(ENABLED)",
    "vip_type": "Consistent (BACKEND)",
    "server_port": "Consistent",
    "vip_server_timeout": "Consistent",
    "vip_client_timeout": "Consistent",
    "persistent_method": "Consistent",
    "persistent_timeout": "2Consistent"
  }  
]; 

var myContacts3 = [{
    "someColumn1": "lorem ipsum 1-1",
    "someColumn2": "lorem ipsum 1-2",
    "someColumn3": "09-03-2020",
    "someColumn4": "lorem ipsum 1-4",
    "someColumn5": 1,
    "someColumn6": "YES",
    "someColumn7": "HTTP",
    "someColumn8": "lorem ipsum 1-8",
    "someColumn9": "lorem ipsum 1-9",
    "someColumn10": "lorem ipsum 1-10",
    "someColumn11": "lorem ipsum 1-11",
    "someColumn12": "lorem ipsum 1-12",
    "someColumn13": "lorem ipsum 1-13",
    "someColumn14": null,
    "someColumn15": "lorem ipsum 1-15",
    "someColumn16": "lorem ipsum 1-16",
  },
  {
    "someColumn1": "lorem ipsum 2-1",
    "someColumn2": "lorem ipsum 2-2",
    "someColumn3": "09-03-2020",
    "someColumn4": "lorem ipsum 2-4",
    "someColumn5": 2,
    "someColumn6": "YES",
    "someColumn7": "HTTP",
    "someColumn8": "lorem ipsum 2-8",
    "someColumn9": "lorem ipsum 2-9",
    "someColumn10": "lorem ipsum 2-10",
    "someColumn11": "lorem ipsum 2-11",
    "someColumn12": "lorem ipsum 2-12",
    "someColumn13": "lorem ipsum 2-13",
    "someColumn14": null,
    "someColumn15": "lorem ipsum 2-15",
    "someColumn16": "lorem ipsum 2-16",
  }  
]; 

//init DataTable
function initDataTable(){
  // first we will destroy the old DataTable if it exists
  if ( $.fn.dataTable.isDataTable('#example') ) {
      $('#example').DataTable().destroy();
      $('#example').empty();
  }
     
  // clearing old column titles
  columns_title = [];
      
  // generating columns.title; https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.title
  // alternatively you could write thead insitde the table and specify column titles
  $.each(jsonTableData[0], function(key) {
      columns_title.push({
      "data": key,
       "title": key
      });
  });

  // initializing the DataTable
  var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
      data: jsonTableData,
      columns: columns_title,
      scrollY:        "300px",
      scrollX:        true,
      scrollCollapse: true,
      paging:         false,
      fixedColumns:   {
          leftColumns: 0,
          rightColumns: 1
      }
  } );
}

// document ready / pick which json to use and run initDataTable()
$(document).ready(function() { 
  // picking which json data to use when the page loads
  jsonTableData = myContacts1;
   initDataTable();
} );


// "dynamically" changing the table
function loadContacts(x){
   switch(x) {
     case 1:
        jsonTableData = myContacts1;
       break;
     case 2:
        jsonTableData = myContacts2;
       break;
     case 3:
        jsonTableData = myContacts3;
       break;          
      default:
          jsonTableData = myContacts1;
    }
  initDataTable();
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.3.0/css/fixedColumns.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.3.0/js/dataTables.fixedColumns.min.js"></script>

<body>

<div>
 <button onclick="loadContacts(1)">Load Contacts 1</button>
  <button onclick="loadContacts(2)">Load Contacts 2</button>
  <button onclick="loadContacts(3)">Load Contacts 3</button>
</div>

<div>
<table id="example" class="stripe row-border order-column" style="width:100%">
</table>
</div>

</body>
```

PS I suggest running the code snippet and then click on "Full page" to better see the results.

PPS I'm guessing the json data is sent by some API, so you should add a check if json data is null.